# Production version on android works differently and unstable.

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have faced an issue of production version working differently from development version on Android. 
In particular, I could not call random functions from events (such as click or window open event), which obviously led to problems.
Same code copy-pasted from standalone function to event function code worked fine, also if you directly hook up the function.

There were also random problems on hooking up OnClick from xml, which required doing it in Javascript.

Anyone else experienced those issues?

Error messages I receive in log are not specific and include full javascript code of the file, minimized and cut off at some point.

Comment: Mystery solved. It was javascript minification issue. When I uncheck that box "Enable javascript minification", all the bugs are magically fixed.